# Get shape of sympy matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to know the shape of a sympy matrix for debugging purposes.
The [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html) suggests the following:

```
from sympy import shape
M = Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [-2, 0, 4]])
shape(M)
```

However this doesn't seem to work on my version of sympy and it doesn't even work in the life shell that is integrated into the sympy documentation website.

In the life shell on [docs.sympy.org](http://docs.sympy.org) it throws the following error:

```
>>> from sympy import shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name shape
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you see `shape` documented as a `sympy` function?

Comment: I can't see where it is in the docs but in sympy 1.8 there is a new shape function. You need to update sympy to use it (SymPy Live is still running 1.5).

Comment: @hpaulj it is [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html), the first point under `basic operations`.

Comment: So sometime between versions 1.5 and 1.8 the function version was added.  But in a fashion often used by `numpy`, it just does `return expr.shape`.  So it's a convenience rather than new functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import sympy
M = sympy.Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [-2, 0, 4]])
M.shape
```

I get

```
(2, 3)
```